# solr 8.9.0 update jetty version of solr 9.4.41 to 9.4.51?

Tags: server, solr, jetty, versionupgrade

i am currently using solr 8.9.0 for my project and i wanted to update my jetty version of solr 9.4.41 to 9.4.51 can anyone help me with that ?

i tried to replace jar with 9.4.51 version of jetty and my solr worked but i haven't replace jetty configurations files[jetty.xml etc..] located inside /server/etc/ folder.
now when i start solr, in log file i can see jetty version 9.4.51 printed.
But using configuration files of 9.4.41 version and jar files of 9.4.51 version i am confused is it okay should i continue is there any problem will occur.
[Btw i also tried to replace configuration files of 9.4.41 version with the configuration files of 9.4.51 version but then after my solr is not working.]

Appreciate your time, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.